# Etymology: to till the land

Tags: etymology, german

OED gives a connection between the German verb *zielen* and the English preposition *till*. The semantic connection between German *zielen* and the verb *till* (cultivating land) seems a bit far-fetched. I would rather see a connection between German *das Land bestellen* and English *to till the land*.

I wonder why this connection is not seen or discussed. And it is for me an example of how easily  in etymology one sticks to similar words as *zielen* even when the semantics is doubtful.

Comment: You are illegitimately comparing modern senses. If you consult an historical dictionary such as [*OED*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdictio101murruoft#page/n39/mode/2up) for the uses and meanings of ancestral forms in English and cognate languages you will find that the semantic connection is perfectly transparent and that there is no need to postulate that a form in /t-/ is cognate with one in /st-/.

Comment: I assume two very similar verbs as OE tilian to strive after and another thatt we have in  OFrisian to cultivate have flown one into the other. And it is not possible to separate them clearly.

Comment: @rogermue: As it turns out, what changes fastest is meanings, and what changes slowest is sounds. And you can tell when the sounds changed because they all changed at once (glacially speaking -- it takes a century or so for a sound change to spread, and there is always detritus), and you can trace the same sound correlation in hundreds of word pairs. Well, dozens to start with, anyway. Isolated pairs are useless; only multiple pairs show relations.

Comment: There's nothing unusual about this semantic change. OED "†1. intr. To strive, exert oneself, labour, work" developed into "4a. trans. To bestow labour and attention, such as ploughing, harrowing, manuring, etc., upon (land) so as to fit it for raising crops; to cultivate."

Comment: The fact that there aren't any cognate pairs where English t : German st pretty much rules out a connection between *till* and *bestellen*.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question was whether "to till the soil" might have some relation with German stellen as in "das Land bestellen". Certainly, a sound change from st to t or vice versa is not the normal thing, but in particular cases something of this kind can happen when words of different word families become similar and one wants to differentiate them. It might well be that in OE tilian several different words have already melted together. The band bredth of tilian is rather large. But such things are impossible to verify.

Comment: @rogermue Modern (West) Frisian still has "tylje" from *tilia, and the Dutch cognate is "telen", with regular e: in open syllable from i. So perfectly constant with "zielen", soundwise.

Answer (score 1):

From etymonline

> till (v.)
>  
>   "cultivate (land)" early 13c.; "plow," late 14c., from Old English tilian "cultivate, tend, work at, get by labor," originally "strive after, aim at, aspire to," related to till "fixed point, goal," and til "good, useful, suitable," from Proto-Germanic *tilojan (cognates: Old Frisian tilia "to get, cultivate," Old Saxon tilian "to obtain," Middle Dutch, Dutch telen "to breed, raise, cultivate, cause," Old High German zilon "to strive," German zielen "to aim, strive"), from source of till (prep.). 
>   **For sense development, compare expression work the land, Old Norse yrkja "work," but especially "cultivate" (and also "to make verses"); Old Church Slavonic delati "work," also "cultivate."** Related: Tilled; tilling.

If the *original* meaning of *tilian* was "strive after, aim at, aspire", the semantic relation to German *zielen* should be clear (as *ziel* mean "goal").

The bold part sounds plausible to me.